# How to run a redis in a docker container for jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, redis, debian

I am trying to install Redis on the `buildpack-deps` docker container.

```
RUN apt-get -y install  redis-server
```

In Jenkinsfile I try to run `redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf`

But I have: 
` FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR

Reading the configuration file, at line 163

logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log

Can't open the log file: Permission denied`

How to install and run redis correctly so that it works when it is assembled on a jenkins in a docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly use the redis-server image to run the redis server.
`docker run --name my-redis -d redis` , the following command would do to run a redis-server in a docker at port 6379.

- you can check the below article out for more details.
- https://www.oskarlind.com/running-a-redis-instance-on-docker/

Comment: it's not entirely clear what you mean. Launch a container of redis in a project container? how is that possible?

Comment: I need to run my project in a container. The project uses redis, redis should also be in this container

Comment: You almost always run one process in a container.  Running Redis in a separate container as this answer suggests is extremely routine, and there’s a related example in the Jenkins documentation on running support containers like this.